# How to combine two HICONs into one

Tags: c++, windows

I have one HICON which I want to use as an overlay on another HICON, to create a result HICON.  The result HICON will then be used in an "owner draw" control (note: it doesn't use imagelists).  The overlay icon has transparency color RGB(0, 255, 0).

How do I go about doing this in Native C++ (I've only found sources that show how to do this with managed code).

Comment: *Way* too hard, GDI has no support whatsoever for this.  Just draw them on top of each other with DrawIcon().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally agree with peterchen's answer, with some notes:

1. There's no reason to work with DIBs (unless you're synthesizing the image directly by altering its bits, rather than drawing using GDI functions).
2. You should keep in mind that `GetIconInfo` actually creates copies of the icon't bitmaps within your process. It's your responsibility to delete them when no more needed.
3. Unless you're going to pass the resulting `HICON` to either standard control or another process - there's just no need to create such. Instead it's better to work with a bitmap (and, possibly, mask).

It's important to understand the difference between icon and bitmap.

- Bitmap is a GDI object. It's valid within your process.
- Icon is a User object, and its scope is not limited to your process. It wraps a bitmap and, optionally, a mask.

There're several icon types:

1. The simplest, consisting of a single bitmap, which is drawn as-is.
2. Bitmap + mask, the mask marks solid/transparent pixels
3. 32-bit bitmap, with alpha channel
4. Monochrome bitmap + mask. The bitmap + mask define the so-called AND-XOR operation (that is performed on the target surface).

So that after you get the contents of the icon (by `GetIconInfo`) you should discover the actual icon type, because each of those options requires different handling.

Answer (score 1):

**(1) overlay Icons**

In many places of the windows API, there are overlay icons supported (e.g. ListView, and TreeView with help ofthe [ImageList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761389%28VS.85%29.aspx#Image_Overlays), also [in the shell](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/overlayicon.aspx))

**(2) As Hans says**
The most straigtforward way would be to

- create a memory DC on a bitmap
- Draw the two icons on top of each other
- create an icon from the bitmap

**(3) if you insist**

If you insist in doing it manually (though i see no reason to):

- `GetIconInfo`to get the underlying bitmaps. Note that b&w icons need special treatment
- `GetObject`the get the BITMAP for a HBITMAP. if you don't also insist on handling various bitmap formats, you should covnert them into DIB sections.
- Do your magic